# complex eigenvalue of self-adjoint matrix

Tags: diagonalization

[image]
I have to diagonalize self-adjoint matrix above. But I cannot solve the characteristic polynomial, which is cubic equation with not noticeable factor.
So when I insert that equation into wolfram alpha, it gives complex value. But thats contradictory, I think, because I have learned that all eigenvalue of Self-adjoint matrix are real.
What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The polynomial $-\lambda^3 + 7 \lambda^2 - 9 \lambda - 1$ does indeed have three real roots, approximately $-.1027750491$, $1.853634511$, $5.249140538$.
Being a cubic, it can be solved in "closed form" using radicals.  However, this is the "[casus irreducibilis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis)": these radicals must involve complex-valued intermediate expressions, even though the end result is real.  If you try to evaluate those expressions numerically, there is a good chance that roundoff error will result in small, but nonzero, imaginary parts.

Alternatively, you can express the roots using trigonometric and inverse-trigonometric functions, and these are manifestly real:

$$ \frac{7}{3} + \frac{2 \sqrt{22}}{3} \cos \left(\frac{\arctan(3 \sqrt{237}/23)+ 2 k \pi}{3} \right),\ k = 0,1,2 $$

Comment: One must admit that computing these values by hand would not be trivial...

Comment: Thanks. I didnt know about the casus irreducibilis. By the way, can u teach me how to get the final values?

Comment: The sum of the three roots is $7$.  $x = \lambda - 7/3$ satisfies $x^3 - \frac{22}{3} x + \frac{92}{27} = 0$.  If $x = b \cos(t)$, $\cos(3t) = 4 \cos(t)^3 - 3 \cos(t) = (4/b^3) (x^3 - (3 b^2/4) x)$.  So take $b = 2 \sqrt{22}/3$, and you get $\cos(3t) = (23/242) \sqrt{22}$.  Thus $t = \pm (1/3) \arccos((23/242) \sqrt{22}) + 2 \pi k/3$.

Comment: For some reason, Maple expressed this using $\arctan$ instead of $\arccos$.

Answer (score 0):

It simply means you made a careless mistake and you encounter a bug at that particular moment.

I inserted the matrix into wolfram alpha and the charactheristic polynomial is

$$-\lambda^3+7\lambda^2-9\lambda - 1$$

and I obtain $3$ distinct real eigenvalues.

Comment: Mathematica gives me hideous expressions for those values though, like this:
$$-\frac{\left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{23+3 i \sqrt{237}}}{3\ 2^{2/3}}+\frac{7}{3}-\frac{11 \left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right)}{3 \sqrt[3]{2 \left(23+3 i \sqrt{237}\right)}}.$$

Comment: Have you tried wolfram alpha? It should be a real number. I wonder if the expression can be simplifed to a real number.